# "Failed to establish session " error getting in Xiaomi phone connection in React Native app

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error when I am running my react-native application for android platform:

> Failed to establish session

I have already enabled debugging option and checked on "Install via USB".

What is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this problems comes from all of Xiaomi phones, MIUI block incoming action for installing adb from apk via usb. If you try install manual via "adb install nameofapk.apk" then of your Xiaomi's screen will pop permission that ask you to accept or deny installation from usb. That's the problem why apk won't automatically install when we type "react-native run-android", because that command use silent install via adb to Xiaomi Device. Silent install will not make pop up permission on Xiaomi's screen. So may the question is, how to remember permission access for install apk via adb usb, or maybe disable it.